# how to insert blob image into oracle through laravel seeder

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, oci8

We are trying to insert a blob from Laravel seeder to oracle 11 g.This was working fine when using mysql database. When using oracle db,running the seeder through command prompt fails and outputs some garbage values.How can we insert an image blob through the Laravel seeder into oracle ?

```
<?php
class TestSeeder extends Seeder {

/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
$jpg_image_filename  = "MMS-CREATE-UTIB-UTIB13117-20032015-375303_detailfront.jpg";  
        $grey_image = new Imagick("/var/www/test/public/images/".$jpg_image_filename);
        $jpg_image_data = $grey_image->getImageBlob();

$tif_image_filename = "MMS-CREATE-UTIB-UTIB13117-20032015-375303_front.tif";
        $bw_image = new Imagick("/var/www/test/public/images/".$tif_image_filename);
        $tif_image_data = $bw_image->getImageBlob();

        $data = array(  

            'JPG_IMAGE1' => $jpg_image_data,
            'TIF_IMAGE1' => $tif_image_data
            );

DB::table('test')->insert($data);
}

}

?>
```